# This spot'd a great food

Tags: pronunciation

I heard [[28:40-28:43] part of this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/H0bA72fjHMQ?t=1720) as '*This spot'd a great food*' which means '*This restaurant served a great food*'

If I heard right, can I use the clause in a colloquial context?

Comment: He seems to say 'This spot did (or had) great food', but speaking so quickly that it's reduced to 'spot'd'. (We wouldn't say '_a_ great food'.)

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you very much.

Comment: The computer-generated subtitle obviously doesn't use particularly smart AI! The text version is *...this **spotted** great food*, but to my ear the spoken version is unquestionably *...this spot **had** great food*. That may reflect a US/UK distinction though - in ***BrE*** I'd expect more of a "semi-glottal stop" if the speaker intended to convey ***...spot did...*** rather than ***...spot had...***

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you very much.